# How to consume HTTPS rest service from android application

Tags: android, rest, ssl, https, certificate

I am very much new to android application development. I am working on a demo project, where I am trying to use my android application as a client of a WCF REST service created on C#.net. The service is already hosted in a internet server and is working fine as I am using the same service in my other .Net web applications (as client).
But when I am trying to access the same REST service (returning a JSON object) from my android application it’s throwing following exception.

**“java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:585 0xaf586674:0x00000000)”**

Following is the code I used to connect the service.

```
final String url = "https://mywebsite.com/service/myservice.svc/userid/" + usrid + "/" + password + "/authenticate";

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpHost host = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), 443, uri.getScheme());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri.getPath());
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(host, httppost);  // Throwing exception on this line
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) { 
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
                JSONArray nameArray=json.names();
                JSONArray valArray=json.toJSONArray(nameArray);
                for(int i=0;i<valArray.length();i++)
                {
                    nameArray.getString(i);
                } 
                instream.close();
            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Should I need to create a SSLContext with my own TrustManager in order to ignore the SSL certificate error please confirm. If yes, could you please provide the code example as well.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have mentioned will work in a real device. The problem that you presented is caused by the firewall in your PC that blocks the 443 port.

Try to disable your firewall and try your application in the emulator. I believe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. You need to create a SSLContext with your own TrustManager in order to ignore the SSL certificate error.

**EasySSLSocketFactory.java**

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;

 import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
 import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

 import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
 import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory;
 import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory;
 import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
 import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory {

private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(null) }, null);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
    if (this.sslcontext == null) {
        this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
    }
    return this.sslcontext;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#connectSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
 *      java.net.InetAddress, int, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
 */
public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort,
        HttpParams params) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
    int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
    int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);
    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

    if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
        // we need to bind explicitly
        if (localPort < 0) {
            localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
        }
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
        sslsock.bind(isa);
    }

    sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
    sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
    return sslsock;

}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#createSocket()
 */
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket)
 */
public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return true;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
 *      boolean)
 */
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
// Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
// for the correct operation of some connection managers
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(EasySSLSocketFactory.class));
}

public int hashCode() {
    return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
}

}
```

**EasyX509TrustManager.java**

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class EasyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

/**
 * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager.
 */
public EasyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    super();
    TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    factory.init(keystore);
    TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
    if (trustmanagers.length == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("no trust manager found");
    }
    this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustmanagers[0];
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
 */
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates, authType);
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
 */
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    if ((certificates != null) && (certificates.length == 1)) {
        certificates[0].checkValidity();
    } else {
        standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);
    }
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers()
 */
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
}

}
```

Now Call Https Service:

```
 String urlToSendRequest = "https://example.com";
            String targetDomain = "example.com";

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

     SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http",    PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), 443));

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, 30);
                params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE, new ConnPerRouteBean(1));
            params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "utf8");
    ClientConnectionManager cm =  new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);

    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(targetDomain, 443, "https");
            // Using POST here
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlToSendRequest);
            // Make sure the server knows what kind of a response we will accept

    // Also be sure to tell the server what kind of content we are sending
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml"); 

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("<input>test</input>", "UTF-8");
            entity.setContentType("application/xml");
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);


CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            //set the user credentials for our site "example.com"
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(targetDomain, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("", ""));
            HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
context.setAttribute("http.auth.credentials-provider", credentialsProvider);

            // execute is a blocking call, it's best to call this code in a
            // thread separate from the ui's
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, context);
```

Comment: Tried this.. error still exists. Adding some more information.. I am trying to access the service from the emulator. And currently even from emulator's browser I can't access any "https" site, "http" s are working fine. Do I need to change any emulator setup for this? Please help..